# Add both .h and .m files in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When I add a new file in Xcode 6.3.2 I see templates for the .m and .h file but how do you add both at once?

I'm sure there used to be a way of adding both at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option has been moved into the more generic "Cocoa Touch Class" template, which allows you to make the class in either Objective-C or Swift.

[image: Cocoa touch class]

Complete the name of your pair of files with the default prefix filled-in for you. Choose the superclass such as `NSObject`. Choose the `Objective-C` language. Click the `Next` button, then choose the folder location where to save your pair of new `.h` and `.m` files.

[image]

Comment: Groan. Struggling to make sense of that. After all, how is a generic library class a Cocoa Touch Class?

Comment: No, does not make any intuitive sense. But it does work as of Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by add new file and "Cocoa Class"